# Converting a part of hard coded sample project in MVC to soft code (pulling the data from the database)

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I'm following along with a sample project from [this website](http://techiesweb.net/2012/10/12/radio-button-list-in-asp-net-mvc.html). I reached a point where he is constructing the GET action method with in this action method he hardcoded the data he using.

I tried everything I could think of to pull the same data from a database but everything failed. I am still a beginner with MVC so I'm asking for some assistance in doing this because I've got a project in mind and it is long the same line as this sample project.

the get action method  looks something like this

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
    var evalVM = new Evaluation();

    var q1 = new Question { ID = 1, QuestionText = "What is your favouritelanguage" };
    q1.Answers.Add(new Answer { ID = 12, AnswerText = "PHP" });
    q1.Answers.Add(new Answer { ID = 13, AnswerText = "ASP.NET" });
    q1.Answers.Add(new Answer { ID = 14, AnswerText = "Java" });
    evalVM.Questions.Add(q1);

    var q2 = new Question { ID = 2, QuestionText = "What is your favourite DB" };
    q2.Answers.Add(new Answer { ID = 16, AnswerText = "SQL Server" });
    q2.Answers.Add(new Answer { ID = 17, AnswerText = "MySQL" });
    q2.Answers.Add(new Answer { ID = 18, AnswerText = "Oracle" });
    evalVM.Questions.Add(q2);

    return View(evalVM);    
}
```

Comment: 'i tried everything i could think of to pull the same data from a database'  - can you show us what you _have_ tried because there is literally nothing to work with so far.

Comment: What is the actual problem? What is failing?

Comment: thanks for your help and guidance what my problem is trying to find away to pull the questions from a database table and also the labels for the radio buttons instead of hard coding it like above i can pull the labels for the radio button from the database  in one view and i can also pull the the questions from the database also in another view but what i cant seem to do is combine them like  what that sample project did  this project does it exactly how i want it to be done but the only thing is that its hard coded and like i said i'm learning mvc as i go along

Answer (score 0):

You need to build a question and answer repository. 2 Tables, a question table and an answer table with a question_answer_id that links the answer to a question (one to many relationship). Then code to pull that information from the database, iterate through each question, create the question, iterate through each answer, create the answer, then finally add the question to Questions. You will probably want the results stored, so a question results table might be necessary that links user answers to questions for later reporting.

> Question

```
 Question_ID
 Description
```

> Answer

```
Answer_ID
Question_Answer_ID
Description
```

Create objects/entities, that represent the columns, and a repository for getting that information.

```
public class Question
{
    public int QuestionID { get; set; }
    public String Description { get; set; }
}

public class Answer
{
    public int AnswerID { get; set; }
    public int QuestionAnswerID { get; set; }
    public String Description { get; set; }
}

public Class QuestionRepository : YourDbConnection
{
    public List<Question> getQuestions()
    {
        List<Question> question = new List<Question>();
        String sql = "SELECT * FROM question";
        Connection connection = getYourDbConnection();
        Command command = connection.CreateCommand();
        command.CommandText = sql;
        DataReader reader = null;
        try
        {
            connection.Open();
            reader = command.ExecuteReader();
            while(reader.Read())
            {
                 Question q = new Question();
                 q.QuestionID = Convert.ToInt32(reader.GetValue(reader.GetOrdinal("QUESTION_ID")));
                 q.Description = reader.GetValue(reader.GetOrdinal("DESCRIPTION")).ToString();
                 questions.Add(q);
            }
            reader.Close();
            connection.Close();
        }
        catch(Exception ex) //readers don't throw database exceptions when attempting to get info by index
        {
            if(reader != null)
                if(!reader.IsClosed)
                    reader.Close();
            connection.Close();
            logger.error("Failed to retrieve questions from the database.", ex);
        }
        return questions;
    }
}
```

pretty much the same for `public List<Answer> getAnswers()`...

Then use linq when building the questionnaire.

```
QuestionRepository questionRepo = new QuestionRepository();
AnswerRepository answerRepo = new AnswerRepository();
List<Question> questions = questionRepo.getQuestions();
List<Answer> answers = answerRepo.getAnswers();

foreach(Question q in questions)
{
   var q1 = new Question { ID = q.QuestionID, QuestionText = q.Description };
   List<Answer> questionAnswers = answers.FindAll(o => o.QuestionAnswerID == q.QuestionID);
    if(questionAnswers != null)
    {
        foreach(Answer a in questionAnswers)
        {
            q1.Answers.Add(new Answer { ID = a.AnswerID, AnswerText = a.Description });
            evalVM.Questions.Add(q1); 
        }
    }
    return evalVM;
}
```

Comment: Haha, I just checked your link you provided. I applied my own implementation and this is not intended to be for you to copy and paste, rather to understand how to automate from hard-coded info to database info.